# Bigcommerce API preorder_release_date

Tags: api, bigcommerce

I am attempting to set a product to "Preorder" status in Bigcommerce via api. I already have a few hundred items up with no issues. Seems like the Date is causing my error 400. I tried every combination of ISO date required, but to no avail

This is a snippet of the json.

```
"categories": [
    9
  ],
  "availability": "preorder",
  "is_free_shipping": true,
  "preorder_message": "Out of Stock, Available for Backorder. Order now and get FREE shipping for this item as a consolation.",
  "preorder_release_date": "2015-07-03T18:07:51",
  "inventory_tracking": "none",
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Bigcommerce docs](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/data-types), dates in requests must be ISO 8601. 
In php, you could use `date('c');`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, tried all 8601 variations, still looking for a solution :(

Comment: Can you post your code please, and I will test. I'll use my own api credentials

Comment: Thanks for the offer, I figured it out yesterday, they are not expecting ISO 8601 but RFC-833 so I found a snipper here but forgot to get the posters name to credit him with the help :(, how do I add code in a reply?      Private Function ToRFC822String(timestamp As DateTime) As String
        Return timestamp.ToString("ddd',' d MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss") + " " + timestamp.ToString("zzzz").Replace(":", "")
    End Function

Comment: Feel free to post your comment as an answer if it has solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Function ToRFC822String(timestamp As DateTime) As String 
Return timestamp.ToString("ddd',' d MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss") + " " + timestamp.ToString("zzzz").Replace(":", "") 
End FunctioN
```